# php on DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR script?

Tags: php

I'm writing absolute paths to make sure that `require_once` works as expected in all of my included files. 
c:/program files (x86)/apache software foundation/apache2.2/htdcos/photo_gallery

I tried with these two examples:

1. `defined("SITE_ROOT")? null : defined("SITE_ROOT","C:".DS."Program Files (x86)".DS."apache software foundation".DS."apache2.2".DS."htdocs".DS."photo_gallery");`
2. `defined("SITE_ROOT")? null : defined("SITE_ROOT".DS."C:".DS."Program Files (x86)".DS."apache software foundation".DS."apache2.2".DS."htdocs".DS."photo_gallery");`

Comment: What exactly is your question / problem?

Comment: you're not being very clear. what are you trying to achieve? what did you expect to happen? what happened instead?

Comment: im trying to write absolute paths to make sure that require_once works as expected in all included file but so far i couldnt do that

Comment: im confused, what is the question. thx

Comment: What errors did you get? `defined` checks if a constant is defined. Your examples say to return null if SITE_ROOT is defined otherwise return a boolean based on whether `"SITE_ROOT".$reallylongstring` is a defined constant.

Comment: i didnt got any error msg its just white nothing on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use assignments inside the ternary operands, especially if there's only one practical outcome. One-liners are nice, but they're not the epitome of practicality.

Second, forward slashes will work fine with Windows as well:

```
if (!defined("SITE_ROOT")) {
    define("SITE_ROOT", "C:/Program Files (x86)/apache software foundation/apache2.2/htdocs/photo_gallery");
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked but what is i want define('DS')? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); instead of using forward slashes

Comment: @mercy If you really want to use your `DS` constant, feel free to use it; I'm just saying that you don't *need* it :)

Comment: thanks, i new to programming specially to php! thanks for u r help

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define the DS as this is not shown.

```
  defined("DS")? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
  defined("SITE_ROOT")? null : define("SITE_ROOT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS. 'photo_gallery');
```

Comment: You have referred to "defined" rather than "define" when actually defining the constants constants in the else part of each statement.

Comment: yes i have define it like these define('DS')? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined("SITE_ROOT")? null : defined("SITE_ROOT".DS."C:".DS."Program Files (x86)".DS."apache software foundation".DS."apache2.2".DS."htdocs".DS."photo_gallery");

Answer (score 0):

You already have defined "SITE_ROOT"

it's in the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] there is no need to reinvent the wheel.
simply concat using this 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' or 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' depending on your needs:

```
$site_root = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'subdirectory';
```

dirname is used to get rid of trailing slashes that might appear: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#97351